# Express serving static asset files relative to the route instead of absolute

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In express I have the following route:

```
app.get('/story/:username', function(req, res){
    res.render('dashboard.ejs');
});
```

And before that I serve any static files located in `/public`:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Now I believed that this was serving the root directory, so that when I visited the path `http://localhost:8080/story/user17` it would still be able to pull my static files such as `css/main.css` from `http://localhost:8080/css/main.css`. Instead when I tried to load the page and checked the console I kept seeing this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/story/css/main.css (404)
```

for all of my static files. Why is it attempting to load my all of static files from a relative directory instead of the absolute root, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the path to your CSS file in `dashboard.ejs` from `css/main.css` to `../css/main.css` so that it can be found from a page the browser sees as `/story/someUser`

Comment: Ah how silly of me, it now works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: What about `/story/someUser/anotherOne/`? Better to change it to `/css/main.css`.

Comment: @AleksandrM It's usually better to keep relative URL so that you can proxy things for example. When you can't, you must keep some track of the server path

Comment: @AleksandrM node/io.js is frequently, for various reasons, behind a proxy. An example : having multiple applications answer on port 80 on the same address.